# VPN Authentication Using AD on Secondary Server

Tags: windows, vpn, domain, authentication, rras

I have two servers, SBS 2003 and Server 2003.  The Server 2003 is running as VPN server and is connected to the domain of the SBS 2003.  I am trying to get the VPN to authenticate domain users.  I can only login to the vpn using a local account on the 2003 Server.  I have tried adding my domain user account to a VPN group and adding that group in the VPN policy.  When I try to login to the VPN it says bad username/password.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure out.  You need to use he Internet Authentication Services program as radius server, which microsoft has built into the os.  http://codeidol.com/windows/inside-windows-server-2003/Managing-Remote-Access-and-Internet-Routing/Configuring-Internet-Authentication-Services-(IAS)/